# DocuSign login_information method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

I'm implementing an API that is written in C# using ASP.NET Web API. The implementation of our API needs to call out to DocuSign e.g. in order to request signatures for contracts. Our application interacts with DocuSign through their REST API.

The question I have is regarding the DocuSign [login_information](https://www.docusign.co.uk/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Login.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____1) REST endpoint. I understand this returns a base Url that should be used in all future Docusign API calls as the base of the request URL.

How often should `login_information` be requested? Is it OK to make a one-off request (from outside of our application) and then store the returned Base Uri in our application configuration, to be used for all DocuSign requests? Or should this method be called from our application e.g. per request, in case the base Url changes?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, I think it should be OK to make a one-off request and store the Base Uri, as mentioned in their [REST API Guide](https://www.docusign.co.uk/sites/default/files/rest-api-guide-v2-2.pdf):

"Note: After using login_information to get the baseUrl, the base Url and apiPassword can be stored by the client. The login_information call is not needed in subsequent sessions, unless another call fails and the user needs to re-authenticate. Each call performs authentication":